How to put a No-ip dns in SPF
I want to whitelist my No-Ip DNS on my SPF record because sometimes it gets targeted as spam because is not listed in permitted senders.
Reading the No-Ip FAQ, it says that I have only to put include:no-ip.com in the SPF record.
That's all? Don't have I to put my DNS too?
Like:
"v=spf1 a:mail.mydoman.com.br ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx include:no-ip.com include:anotherdomain.zapto.org include:_spf.google.com ~all"

What do you mean "my DNS"?
Depending on what you have setup, and where you're sending email from, what you have listed there potentially looks fine to me.
The purpose of an include: is to effectively add other existing SPF records in your own. So for instance, the include:no-ip.com effectively adds all their sending IP addresses, without you needing to maintain that list. When they add/remove entries from their SPF that is picked up by anyone including it.
So in this instance you've included the SPF entries for no-ip.com, Google, and anotherdomain.zapto.org, and also explicitely included an IPv4 address, and whereever mail.mydomain.com.br resolves to. So if all of your emails come from one of those sources then you're all set.
You could possibly do without the include:anotherdomain.zapto.org entry since that simply points to the include:no-ip.com record you've already included, so just adds duplication for no reason.

The instructions do not include any additional requirements your domain has for the SPF record, as those will be specific to each domain.

So in this case I have to put my domains in the include tag not the no-ip.com, right?
